# Re-login of several ASP.NET MVC apps on the same server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have several ASP.NET MVC 3 apps running on IIS 6 with separate app pools under different virtual directories:

```
http://192.168.1.2/theapp
http://192.168.1.2/otherapp
```

All uses forms authentication.

The problem is that whenever I log in to one application, the other applications get logged out.

I have set up machine keys for each apps, all different.

What else did I miss so I can log in to all apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check what is the path defined for the Forms Authentication. If it is set to root, both applications conflict with each other.

Try setting something like that in web.config (notice the `path` attribute):

```
  <forms loginUrl="~/admin/AdminLogin.aspx" timeout="20" path="/theapp">
  </forms>
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx and note the **Path** explanation.

Comment: I added 'path' into the <forms>, but now each app asks for login over and over?

Comment: Found the problem, it's CASE SENSITIVE!